# No mapping for GET / in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dispatcher

I am trying to build Spring MVC web app. 
The problem is in my welcome-page (localhost:8080/). In my output log I am seeing:
 **No mapping for GET /**

I set my welcome page to URL: **"/spring-mvc-login"** but everytime I restart app it is trying to look for URL **"/"** which is not serve in my controller. I want **to redirect welcome page** to URL **"/spring-mvc-login"** but it doesnt work.

Funny thing is that when I type "localhost:8080/spring-mvc-login" it is working fine. The only problem is to redirect this URL to welcome-page.

**WEB.XML**

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/spring-mvc-login</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

**todo-servlet.xml**

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And **Controller**

```
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/spring-mvc-login", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(){
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/spring-mvc-login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String handleLoginRequest(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String password,
                                         ModelMap modelMap){
        modelMap.put("name",name);
        modelMap.put("password", password);
        return "welcome";

        }

}
```

In **Controller** when i change @RequestMapping from "/spring-mvc-login "to "/" it is working fine of course but I want to redirect my welcome page to "/spring-mvc-login" not to "/". Thanks for help.

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you create your package and classes in **src/main/java** NOT in **src/main/resources**.
If maven doesn't create the src/main/java folder, just create the folder and move the package folders/classes there.
Doing this resolved the no mapping error for me.

Hope this information will be useful to someone.

Comment: It really helped me. I was fed-up whole day for the same. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use @RestController annotation.
If you want to redirect use:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void redirect(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws Exception {

     httpResponse.sendRedirect("/spring-mvc-login");
}
```

Comment: I am using @Controller annotation. When i add this it's working but is it the proper way to set welcome page?

Comment: I would use spring-boot-security package to set it all up. There you can have / landing page and set redirect if someone not authenticated. You can set context  to /spring-mvc-login, but that would be weird.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove "/"

before

```
<welcome-file>/spring-mvc-login</welcome-file>
```

after

```
<welcome-file>spring-mvc-login</welcome-file>
```

Comment: I have the same error "No mapping for GET /" so no change

Comment: You are missing these annotations in your controller class @Controller
@RequestMapping("/")

Comment: I didnt serve URL "/", because I thought that I can redirect welcome page in my WEB.xml to adress "/spring-mvc-login"

Comment: of course when I add this @RequestMapping("/")  annotation it is working fine. But how can I redirect my welcome page to adress "/spring-mvc-login" in WEB.xml? Is this can be done only in Controller Class?

Comment: Is there any reason in particular? Spring facilitates this with only return a String, it is the new

Answer (score 1):

Put @Controller annotation on top of the Controller class

Comment: it works better with the right annotation ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change web.xml content:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or change controller mapping to:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/", "/spring-mvc-login"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check once in `spring-servlet.xml` file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.----"></context:component-scan>
```

Specifically base-package name.